# SubSet whose sum is greatest but less than a particular value

Tags: vba, algorithm, excel, knapsack-problem, sub-array

I have an array with positive values.
For e.g array= {5,4,4,3.8,2,1.7}
I need to find a  subarray whose sum is largest but  less than 12 .
In this case it will be {4,4,3.8}

another ex array {7,4,3,2}
In this case max sum is 12 and subset is {7,3,2}

what will be the algorithm for it  as i have very large array whose length is more than 1000.
I am writing this programme in VBA excel.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the attempt you have made.

Comment: 1000 is not so large. If the length of your array is not much larger than 1000, you can afford a quadratic complexity -- and it's not very difficult to consider _every_ subarray sum then.

Comment: There's no counter example in `{5,4,4,3.8,2,1.7}`, but by "subarray" do you mean *set* (i.e. any group of numbers) or *sequence*.

Comment: This is an NP-complete problem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: @yogsototh Not at all. A naive algorithm can clearly find a solution in quadratic time. The problems you link to are unrelated (or much more general).

Comment: @Nelxiost This is exactly like those problems if OP means subsets instead of subsequences. If he means subsequences, then a brute-force quadratic solution is indeed possible. That's why Comintern asked.

Comment: @Mikegrann True. But "subarray" usually means "subsequence" (contiguous). Then again, the question should probably specify it, and show a better example.

Comment: @Comintem yes set (i.e any group and any length of subarray)

Comment: If you really mean set as opposed to subarray (and your last comment only reinforced the ambiguity) this is clearly infeasible as it is an NP-complete discrete optimization problem with a search space of  over 2^1000 elements. Your best bet would be to use a branch-and-bound algorithm, which is implemented in the solver (if you constrain some variables to be binary or integer and specify linear). Unfortunately, the free-version of the solver which ships with Excel can't handle 1000+ binary variables. You could purchase an upgrade to the premium solver or find an open source alternative.

Answer (score 2):

try this algorithm for subsequence

```
Sub aargh()
Dim a As Variant
Dim limsum As Double, highestnum As Double
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    a = Array(5, 4, 4, 3.8, 2, 1.7)
    limsum = 12

    highestsum = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
        s = a(i)
        j = i
        Do
            If s > highestsum Then fs = i: ls = j: highestsum = s
            j = j + 1
            If j > UBound(a) Then Exit Do
            s = s + a(j)
        Loop While s <= limsum
    Next i
    MsgBox "subarray (" & fs & "," & ls & ") sum = " & highestsum
End Sub
```

edited to include the remarks below and to include a solution for subset

```
Sub aargh()

    Dim sol(), csol()
    a = Array(7, 4, 3, 2)

    ReDim sol(LBound(a) To UBound(a))
    ReDim csol(LBound(a) To UBound(a))
    limsum = 13
    findsum a, sol, csol, maxsum, limsum
    ss = "array "
    For i = 1 To sol(0)
        ss = ss & sep & a(sol(i))
        sep = ","
    Next i
    MsgBox ss & " sum =" & maxsum
End Sub
Sub findsum(ByRef a, ByRef sol, ByRef csol, ByRef maxsum, ByRef limsum, Optional s = 0, Optional lvl = 1, Optional si = 0)
' recursive sub
    For i = si To UBound(a)
        s = s + a(i)
        csol(lvl) = i ' current solution contains number i
        If s <= limsum Then
            If s > maxsum Then ' we found a sum greater than current max we save it
                maxsum = s
                sol(0) = lvl
                For j = 1 To lvl
                    sol(j) = csol(j)
                Next j
            End If
            If i < UBound(a) Then ' pick another number
                findsum a, sol, csol, maxsum, limsum, s, lvl + 1, i + 1
            End If
        End If
        s = s - a(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

code optimized if array is sorted (descending)

```
Sub aargh()

    Dim sol(), csol()
    a = Array(20, 15, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2)

    ReDim sol(LBound(a) To UBound(a))
    ReDim csol(LBound(a) To UBound(a))
    limsum = 13
    findsum a, sol, csol, maxsum, limsum, UBound(a)
    ss = "array "
    For i = 1 To sol(0)
        ss = ss & sep & a(sol(i))
        sep = ","
    Next i
    MsgBox ss & " sum =" & maxsum
End Sub
Sub findsum(ByRef a, ByRef sol, ByRef csol, ByRef maxsum, ByRef limsum, si, Optional s = 0, Optional lvl = 1)
' recursive sub
    For i = si To LBound(a) Step -1
        If s + a(i) > limsum Then Exit For
        s = s + a(i)
        csol(lvl) = i    ' current solution contains number i
        If s <= limsum Then
            If s > maxsum Then    ' we found a sum greater than current max we save it
                maxsum = s
                sol(0) = lvl
                For j = 1 To lvl
                    sol(j) = csol(j)
                Next j
            End If
            If i > LBound(a) Then    ' pick another number
                findsum a, sol, csol, maxsum, limsum, i - 1, s, lvl + 1
            End If
        End If
        s = s - a(i)
        If maxsum = limsum Then Exit For 'exit if exact match
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably want `For i = 0 To UBound(a)`. Otherwise, you won't allow the subsequence to start (and end) at the last element. So for instance, if your settings were `a = Array(5, 4, 4, 3.8, 2, 13.9)` and `limsum = 14` then you'd want to return the subsequence (5,5) w/ sum 13.9 instead of the subsequence (1,4) w/ sum 13.8. Nice brute-force solution otherwise.

Comment: I have checked your code but its not giving the correct result for this array (7, 4, 3, 2)  max sum should be 12 with subset (7,3,2) but its giving sum =11

Comment: @Abhishek Did you edit the value of `limsum`? That's the sum-limiting number. For some reason h2so4 set it to 13 instead of 12. If you modify it to 12, you'll find it works fine for your example. However, it works on subsequences instead of subsets (because the problem wasn't very well-defined). If you really want subsets instead, you'd be best off looking into some algorithms for the Knapsack Problem (as linked in the comments).

Comment: Actually what I meant to ask is subset numbers need not to be continuous. They can be of any group of numbers.

Comment: @Mikegrann I have also searched for knapsack problem but did not find any solution. Can u please guide me or give me the related link for this.

Comment: @Abhishek https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Solving has some pseudocode and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knapsack-problem has plenty of StackOverflow questions and discussion.

Comment: @h2so4 Thanks a lot .. really appreciate . you solved my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @Abhishek could you validate this solution as your problem is solved Thanks

Comment: I have checked this code for various array and i think its giving the correct output. Actually i have an array of around 4000 values But when i run this code it took like forever . Can u suggest some idea by which i can reduce the run time. One thing i did was i exit findsum sub when  the maxsum is equal to 12.

Comment: the time needed to solve this kind of problem is proportional to n! so with n around 4000 values it will take like forever. Exiting findsum when maxsum is equal to 12 is a clever optimization.

Comment: another optimization is to sort the array (ascendingly) and exit the for loop as soon as the sum is greather than 12.

Comment: @h2so4  if we impose the condition on maximum and minimum length of subarray. For e.g I have an an array of 10 numbers.And i want the array with min length of 3 and max length of 6..Will it help in optimization. what will be the modification in above code??

Comment: @h2so4 which loop?? I have a sorted array in descending order

Answer (score 0):

As multiple people have mentioned in comments this is a simple variation of [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). In order to solve this exact problem you just need to remember the maximum number you find that is less than or equal to `12`.

A simple recursive abroach would be as follows:

```
list = [...]
N = length of list
dp[ maximum possible sum ][ N ]

f(‌current_sum, index):
  if dp[current_sum][index] is set
    return dp[current_sum][index]
  if index >= N
    if current_sum > 12
       result = 0
    else
       result = current_sum
  else
    result = max( f(current_sum, index+1), f(current_sum+list[index], index+1)
  dp[current_sum][index] = result
  return result

result = f(0,0) // this will return the desired result
```